# Pandas: for matching row indices - update dataframe values with values from other dataframe with a different column size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm struggling with updating values from a dataframe with values from another dataframe using the row index as key. Dataframes are not identical in terms of number of columns so updating can only occur for matching columns. Using the code below it would mean that df3 yields the same result as df4. However df3 returns a None object.

Anyone who can put me in the right direction? It doesn't seem very complicated but I can't seem to get it right

ps. In reality the 2 dataframes are a lot larger than the ones in this example (both in terms of rows and columns)

````
import pandas as pd


data1 = {'A': [1, 2, 3,4],'B': [4, 5, 6,7],'C':[7,8,9,10]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1,index=['I_1','I_2','I_3','I_4'])
print(df1)

data2 = {'A': [10, 40], 'B': [40, 70]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2 ,index=['I_1','I_4'])
print(df2)

df3 = df1.update(df2)
print(df3)

data4 =  {'A': [10, 2, 3,40],'B': [40, 5, 6,70],'C':[7,8,9,10]}
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data4 ,index=['I_1','I_2','I_3','I_4'])
print(df4)
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame.update` returns None. The method directly changes calling object.

source: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html

for your example this means two things.

- update returns none. hence `df3=none`
- `df1` got changed when `df3 = df1.update(df2)` gets called. In your case `df1` would look like `df4` from that point on.

to write `df3` and leave `df1` untouched this could be done:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'A': [1, 2, 3,4],'B': [4, 5, 6,7],'C':[7,8,9,10]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1,index=['I_1','I_2','I_3','I_4'])
print(df1)

data2 = {'A': [10, 40], 'B': [40, 70]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2 ,index=['I_1','I_4'])
print(df2)

#using deep=False if df1 should not get affected by the update method
df3 = df1.copy(deep=False) 
df3.update(df2)
print(df3)

data4 =  {'A': [10, 2, 3,40],'B': [40, 5, 6,70],'C':[7,8,9,10]}
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data4 ,index=['I_1','I_2','I_3','I_4'])
print(df4)
```

Comment: The deep parameter doesn't seem to make a difference. In both cases df1 remains unaffacted by the update method. However the copying does indeed the trick and df3 is as expected. Thanks a lot. Would have taken ages before I found this.